# How to sum over the updated sum value in SQL

Tags: sql, sum

How to sum over the updated value by affecting the sum of the values in a different column in the sum of the values in the column?

I want to get result as SumC

| day_no | RATE_A | VALUE_A | SumC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 0 | 40 | 90 |
| 3 | %6 | 0 | 95,4 |
| 4 | 0 | 20 | 115,4 |
| 5 | 0 | 10 | 125,4 |
| 6 | %8 | 0 | 135,4 |
| 7 | 0 | 5 | 140,4 |

i tried  sum with case functions but i couldnt get it

```sql
CREATE TABLE `New_Temp`.`Temp` (
  `day_no` INT NULL,
  `rate` INT NULL,
  `amount` INT NULL);

INSERT INTO `New_Temp`.`Temp` (`day_no`,`rate`,`amount`)
VALUES  (1,0,50)
        ,(2,0,40)
        ,(3,6,0)
        ,(4,0,20)
        ,(5,0,10)
        ,(6,8,0)
        ,(7,0,5)
```

Comment: Your example is very unclear.   What is Day_No?    How is SumC computed because the 3rd and 4th row don't look right.   Using actual column names and show the expected output

Comment: sorry about that, this is my first question, i edited the post to make the question clearer

Comment: What is `%6` and `95,4` supposed to be? This is not clear at all.

Comment: ok i ll check tomorrow it's gonna be hard to understand as a newbie:)

Comment: tkanks a lot Dmitry K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a recursive query for such things.

Here is a query that does what you want for MySQL 8:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE sum_with_perc AS (
    SELECT *, CAST(amount AS FLOAT) AS c_sum
    FROM Temp
    WHERE day_no = 1

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        Temp.*,
        CASE
            -- SUM + percents
            WHEN Temp.rate > 0 THEN sum_with_perc.c_sum + Temp.amount + ((sum_with_perc.c_sum + Temp.amount) * Temp.rate) / 100
            ELSE sum_with_perc.c_sum + Temp.amount
        END
    FROM Temp
    JOIN sum_with_perc ON Temp.day_no = sum_with_perc.day_no + 1
)
SELECT 
    day_no,
    rate,
    amount,
    ROUND(c_sum, 1) AS SumC
FROM sum_with_perc;
```

See output on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mFyDXO5T)
Read more about recursive queries in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive)

Here is a query that does what you want for PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE sum_with_perc AS (
    -- select first row
    SELECT *, "VALUE_A"::numeric AS c_sum
    FROM recs
    WHERE day_no = 1

    UNION ALL
    
    -- recursive part goes here
    SELECT 
        recs.*,
        CASE
            -- SUM + percents
            WHEN recs."RATE_A" > 0 THEN sum_with_perc.c_sum + recs."VALUE_A" + ((sum_with_perc.c_sum + recs."VALUE_A") * recs."RATE_A") / 100
            ELSE sum_with_perc.c_sum + recs."VALUE_A"
        END
    FROM recs
    JOIN sum_with_perc ON recs.day_no = sum_with_perc.day_no + 1
),
-- recs CTE is just for simulating real table
recs AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            (1, 0, 50),
            (2, 0, 40),
            (3, 6.0, 0),
            (4, 0, 20),
            (5, 0, 10),
            (6, 8.0, 0),
            (7, 0, 5)
    ) s (day_no, "RATE_A", "VALUE_A")
)
SELECT 
    day_no,
    "RATE_A",
    "VALUE_A",
    ROUND(c_sum, 1) AS "SumC"
FROM sum_with_perc;
```

See output of this query on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0otgV2nQ)

Read more about [recursive queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE)

**UPD**:
See the PostgreSQL query port for MySQL 8 on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fen8qK1f)